# thead not printing on each page for IE9

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a report which is contained within a table. I use a `<thead>` for the table header, with the style `display: table-header-group;`, in an attempt to print the header on each page when printing. This works fine in most browsers, with the exception of IE 9.

Unfortunately, I cannot give the actual code as it is an order containing proprietary information. I have tried several doctypes, but cannot seem to get IE 9 to print the table head on each page when printing to a printer. Has anyone run in to this issue and know of a fix?

**HTML**

```
<table id="pt">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <td colspan="4">
                <h1>egdfgsdfg</h1>
                <h3>sdfgsdfg</h3>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="align-right">
                <h2>sdfgsdfg</h2>
                sdfgsdfgsdfg
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="contacts">
            <td colspan="3">sdfgsdfg</td>
            <td colspan="3">sdfgsdfgs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header-info">                
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="column-headers">               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pt thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

Comment: Is the HTML structure proprietary, too? Why not post that without the content (or with dummy content)?

Comment: @EvanMulawski sure i guess. formatting gonna be all jacked up due to having to delete a bunch of php and replace with dummy text.

Comment: I know a solution - output it to a PDF. TCPDF works pretty great for this type of thing.

Comment: For instance, [TCPDF examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php), one of which is [HTML tables with header and rowspan](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps).

Comment: @JaredFarrish thank you for this, but it would not be ideal in this particular situation.

Comment: Alright, thought I'd mention it. Here's a working demo which shows the problem in IE9: http://jfcoder.com/test/thead.html

Comment: Actually, hmm. After I put the style in (forgot about it) it does appear in print preview to put the header on each page. Do you have the same problem with the file on my site?

Comment: i'll check in a minute. the pcs with ie9 are occupied by someone else atm. i noticed you used no doctype declaration. perhaps this would fix my problem.

Comment: What `doctype` are you using? Also, here is what I see on page two in print preview: http://imgur.com/EAPTG

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'compatibility' setting via the dev tools of IE and see if it works. You may have to use the META tag to force that if in fact setting that works. Just to see if it is some css somewhere or an actual IE 9 thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying all the CSS attributes yourself

```
<style type="text/css" media="print,screen" >
th {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

thead {
    display:table-header-group;
}

tbody {
    display:table-row-group;
}
tfoot { 
     display: table-footer-group; 
}
</style>

<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>#i#</td>
                <td>First Name #i#</td>
                <td>Last Name #i#</td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

"If a table contains multiple elements with 'display: table-header-group', only the first is rendered as a header; the others are treated as if they had 'display: table-row-group'" - W3.org

So, I hope you don't have multiple tables with that attribute on the same page.

Like it has been suggested by Kelly, it would be a good idea to check if compatibility is causing the issue. Use this in the head section of your document and see if it helps:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

What about try to change all `<td>` tags within `<thead>` to `<th>` tags ?

Like that, and see?

```
<table id="pt" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th colspan="4">
                <h1>egdfgsdfg</h1>
                <h3>sdfgsdfg</h3>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" class="align-right">
                <h2>sdfgsdfg</h2>
                sdfgsdfgsdfg
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="contacts">
            <th colspan="3">sdfgsdfg</th>
            <th colspan="3">sdfgsdfgs</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header-info">                
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="column-headers">               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>               
            <th>asdfadfasdf</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in markup or styles outside those posted with the question, as Jared Farrish implied in his comments. The following html contains the markup and styles as posted, but with the body row repeated enough times to create two printed pages. IE9 displays the headers on both pages of the print preview using all Browser Mode/Document Mode combinations I tested.

**Browser Mode/Document Modes tested:**

- Internet Explorer 9/Quirks
- Internet Explorer 9/Internet Explorer standards
- Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility Mode/Quirks
- Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility Mode/Internet Explorer standards

**IE9 print preview:**

[image: IE9 print preview]

**IE9 version details:**

[image: IE9 version details]

**Full code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#pt thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}
</style>
<body>
<table id="pt">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <td colspan="4">
                <h1>egdfgsdfg</h1>
                <h3>sdfgsdfg</h3>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="align-right">
                <h2>sdfgsdfg</h2>
                sdfgsdfgsdfg
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="contacts">
            <td colspan="3">sdfgsdfg</td>
            <td colspan="3">sdfgsdfgs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header-info">                
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="column-headers">               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>               
            <td>asdfadfasdf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```